# relation between volume of the universal cover and fundamental group?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, ricci-flow

Lately, I am trying to understand the 1982 Hamilton's paper tilted "three-manifold with positive Ricci curvature". In order to get a uniformly lower bound for the scalar curvature, he used an argument about the relation between the volume of universal cover and the fundamental group as in the image below, that is $X$ has volume one, then the volume of its universal cover $Y$ is just number of elements in the fundamental group of $X$. [image: huy]

Anyone can give me proof of this? thank you !!

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that the universal covering map is a $|\pi_1(X)|$-sheeted covering of $X$?

Comment: No, can you give me a reference for this?

Comment: You can learn about the relation between covering spaces and the fundamental group in many topology textbooks. I recomment Munkres' book "Topology".

Comment: The particular result comes from the construction of the universal cover, wherein the points above a point $x$ essentially *are* the elements of $\pi_1(X,x)$. [This page](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/math432/Universal_Cover.pdf) goes through the construction quite succinctly, assuming some background knowledge in general topology and fundamental groups.